# In C is a function loaded into memory when it is first called or when the program starts? And can it be unloaded from memory?

Tags: c, function, memory

For example:

If I have a function named `void Does_Stuff(int arg)` and call it in the main function, is void Does_Stuff loaded into memory ONLY when it is first called? Or is it loaded into memory during program initialization?

And after calling Does_Stuff in main, can I manually unload it from memory?

For reference the operating system I am running is Windows 7 and I am compiling with MinGW.

Comment: It depends on the OS.

Comment: It is the job of a demand-paged virtual memory operating system to load the code into RAM when you call it.  Nothing you do to help, it is automagic.  You are not supposed to talk about those kind of details when you use the [c] tag.  Especially not when you don't mention the operation system that executes your code.

Comment: Yeah, it's one of those dirty little secrets we like to sweep under the rug.

Comment: @HansPassant: Doesn't hurt to ask.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In simple terms (with the usual depends-on-various-platform-things caveat), **the code for your normal, global C function is "loaded into memory" at the time the program is loaded. You cannot request that it be "unloaded".**

That said, as Hans mentions in a comment, the OS *at a lower level* is in charge of what bits of stuff are important enough to be present in physical RAM, and may choose to "page out" memory that isn't being used frequently. This isn't per-function, and has no knowledge of the structure of your code. So in that sense the function's code may *happen* at various times exist in actual RAM or not. But this is a level below the application's execution, where a C function is always "present and available".

Answer (score 2):

DLL's called by your code could conceivably come and go as you call them.  But your main program *.exe should go all-in at start time.

Answer (score 1):

Though the exact details depend on the compiler, linker, platform and implementation, typically all the functions in your program are loaded into memory by the executable loader of the OS and reside there until the program terminates. This memory is also typically static (though certain programs can and do rewrite parts of themselves), so it's read-only.

Now every time you call a function and pass it an argument, that argument is added to memory (a different memory in principal than where the functions are), and removed again when the function call returns (this is a simplified version).

Answer (score 1):

On some platforms (for instance, DOS) your whole program resides in memory while it runs. On other platforms, it might be swapped out of memory while not running (for instance, ancient UNIX versions). On most platforms your program is splitted into pages of usually 4 kilobytes. When you access a page that is not yet loaded, the operating system produces the required page for you transparently (i.e. you don't notice that at all). If the operating system runs out of memory it may swap out single pages. You cannot control this at all from inside your program.

If you want to be able to control what is in memory and what not, you might wan to read about memory mapping and the mmap system call.

Comment: Once upon a time, there was a technique called _overlaying_. Overlaying was a rudimentary form of virtual memory, used at least since the DOS days. Overlay files, usually named with the `.ovl` extension, contained blocks of code or data which could be swapped in or out the main memory, sometimes manually, and this mechanism could also be explored to implement libraries and other forms of dynamic linking. In those days, a function _could_ be explicitly loaded and unloaded, much in the same manner as a modern dynamic library can.